# Как правильно указать путь к файлу, QFile

Tags: qt

Код:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow *window = new MainWindow(0);
    window->show();

    QFile styleSheetFile;

   //styleSheetFile.setFileName("./styleSheet.css");
   styleSheetFile.setFileName("C:/Users/Arthur/Desktop/build-kyrsach-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug/styleSheet.css");

    styleSheetFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QString qssString = styleSheetFile.readAll();
    a.setStyleSheet(qssString);
    if(styleSheetFile.exists())
        qDebug() << "[styleSheet loaded]";
    return a.exec();
}
```

Пытался указать путь первым способом:

```
styleSheetFile.setFileName("./styleSheet.css");
```

Компилятор не видел файл, в консоли выводило следующее:

```
QIODevice::read (QFile, ".\styleSheet.css"): device not open
```

Попробовал указать полный путь, получилось, но это, к сожалению, не подходит, т.к. предстоит запускать программу на другой машине, где путь будет, конечно же, другой. Как открыть файл без указания полного пути?

Answer (score 2):

```
styleSheetFile.setFileName(a.applicationDirPath() + "//styleSheet.css");
```

Answer (score 0):

Положите файл `styleSheet.css` в папку с ехе и открывайте так:

```
styleSheetFile.setFileName(a.applicationDirPath() + "/styleSheet.css");
```

---

И я бы сделал тот код примерно вот так:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QFile styleSheetFile(a.applicationDirPath() + "/styleSheet.css");
if (styleSheetFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
    // Скорее даже так:
    // QTextStream in(&styleSheetFile);
    // QString qssString = in.readAll();

    QString qssString = styleSheetFile.readAll();
    a.setStyleSheet(qssString);

    qDebug() << "[styleSheet loaded]";
    styleSheetFile.close();

} else {
    qDebug() << "[styleSheet dont loaded]:" << styleSheetFile.errorString();
}
```

Comment: Попробовал, не получается. Файл styleSheet.css лежит по пути, указанном в моем коде выше. По полному пути открывается, но как указали Вы - нет :(

Comment: Сборка может быть релизной и дебажной, у них разные папки, убедитесь, что не перепутали их

Comment: Да. проверял несколько раз. Папку с релизной сборкой вообще удалил. Файл 100% находится в папке с экзешником.

Comment: Быть того не может. Что-нибудь пишется в консоли при запуске? Как вы поняли что файл тот не открывается? Варианты решения: 1. Удалите все сгенерированные папки, запустите сборку и после того как снова появится папки, киньте туда файлик. 2. Используйте файл ресурсов, чтобы "зашить" файл в ехе, тогда не придется с ним носиться, но и изменить после компиляции не выйдет, т.к. он будет в ехе.

Comment: @Justskip, попробуйте такой код. У меня подозрение что дело в том, что папка исполнения отличается при запуске в Qt Creator'е. Т.е. если бы попробовали запустить сам ехе из его папки, то проблем не было. Поэтому одним из решений будет указывание пути через applicationDirPath, чтобы всегда файл искался в папке с ехе, а не от того из какой папки был запуск произведен. Чтобы вы не запустались запустите: `qDebug() << QDir::currentPath();` и `qDebug() << a.applicationDirPath();` и вы поймете о какой разнице я говорил